# Backbone: how to manipulate elements outside the element associated with View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My html structure is:

```
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="screen">
</div>
```

My Backbone View is associated with screen. How to hide/show element in header?

Comment: Your view should only manipulate it's own content. For other stuff maybe let it emit some events to other views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *direct* answer is:

There's nothing special backbone will do for you here. Do it like you would do had backbone not existed at all.

The *correct* answer is:

If you need to manipulate UI elements outside of your view model, your view model is wrong - fix it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the backbone structure & logic - your headerview or screenview should throw an event, in which header view should listen to. If that event happens - then headerview should hide itself.